# Getting Letter of recommendation with letter head

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

So I did my engineering back in 2010. I do know few of my teachers but none of them are now in the same university.

I want to get an academic reference letter for admission on postgraduate level in UK universities.

Would it be fine if I get recommendation letter from my teachers. Of course then the recommendation will be without letter head. So it would be preferable to get recommendation on university letter head?

Comment: Does anyone actually care about letterhead?

Comment: @JeffE I have seen some programs where they specifically require the letters to be with letterhead.

Comment: Oh, I know that the instructions _say_ that letterhead is required.  But does anyone _actually_ care, now that letters are electronic files instead of pieces of paper?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be an issue if they use letterhead of their present employer. They will probably say something about the change of affiliation. But it might be improper for them to submit on the old employer's letterhead.

But a letter on plain paper should also be fine, assuming that the letter writer provides contact information so that their affiliation can be checked if necessary.

Or you can also indicate in application materials that the affiliations of letter writers are new.

Note that I'm retired and so have no current affiliation, but my last employer is happy enough for me to use their letterhead and has provided me with an electronic template for it. Perhaps that is available to your writers as well if it seems important.